# IF the field is blank, how do I not make it loop in my PHP code?

Tags: php, wordpress, function

Here's the code that I got.

```
<?php
function category_image () {
    if (function_exists('z_taxonomy_image_url')) {
        foreach (get_the_category() as $cat) :
        ?>
            <a href="<?php echo get_category_link($cat->term_id); ?>" alt="<?php echo $cat->cat_name; ?>"><img src="<?php echo z_taxonomy_image_url($cat->term_id); ?>" /></a>
        <?
        endforeach;
    }
}
?>
```

So I want to make it that **IF** `z_taxonomy_image_url` is blank, do not run the code. Right now it's displaying the image whether there's an image or not because the function at all times.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: I'm confused. Is `z_taxonomy_image_url` a field, like you say in your question, or a function, as you're using `function_exists`?

Comment: Yeah, nowhere in your code is there a condition testing if a variable (or function return value) is an empty string. I'm gonna have to ask you to go ahead and add that functionality. Mmmmmmk? Greeeaatt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add an `if(!z_taxonomy_image_url($cat->term_id)) continue;` in your code before echo. Something like this:

```
<?php
function category_image () {
    if (function_exists('z_taxonomy_image_url')) {
        foreach (get_the_category() as $cat) :
        if(!z_taxonomy_image_url($cat->term_id)) continue;
        ?>
            <a href="<?php echo get_category_link($cat->term_id); ?>" alt="<?php echo $cat->cat_name; ?>"><img src="<?php echo z_taxonomy_image_url($cat->term_id); ?>" /></a>
        <?
        endforeach;
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: This one worked the best. Thanks! The others didn't seem to work for me.

Answer (score 1):

You need to check if function exists, and also if applying it does not give a blank string - like so

```
<?php
function category_image () {
    if (function_exists('z_taxonomy_image_url') && trim(z_taxonomy_image_url($cat->term_id)) !="") {
        foreach (get_the_category() as $cat) :
        ?>
            <a href="<?php echo get_category_link($cat->term_id); ?>" alt="<?php echo $cat->cat_name; ?>"><img src="<?php echo z_taxonomy_image_url($cat->term_id); ?>" /></a>
        <?
        endforeach;
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

this is my first attempt to help someone in here. :-)
If you wanna check if the function "z_taxonomy_image_url()" returns an empty string you can do it as i have illustrated here. You can also use the strlen() function to count characters.

I hope it helps. :-)

```
<?
function category_image () {
    if (z_taxonomy_image_url() = "") {
        $output '';
        foreach (get_the_category() as $cat){
            $ouput += '<a href="'.get_category_link($cat->term_id).'" alt="'.$cat->cat_name.'"><img src="'.z_taxonomy_image_url($cat->term_id).'" /></a>';
        }
        echo $output;
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

As far I can see you are only checking whether the function exists, do you want to verify if function exists and then run the loop or you actually want to run the 'z_taxonomy_image_url' function and depending on the result function provides to start the loop?